# systemd: How do you query a service's status?

Tags: systemd, services

In sys-v-init, to query a service's status you can use the `service` command and do a `service $NAME_OF_SERVICE status`.

**In systemd, how do you query a service's status?**

Comment: On some systems you can still use `service` but `systemctl` is the safe bet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To query the status of a service in systemd you can do:

[`systemctl status $NAME_OF_SERVICE`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd)